# Back button returning to the login page

Tags: jquery, cordova, local-storage, session-cookies

I have a web app that I am developing with phonegap in which the index page is the login page / registration page.

This is fine as this is the first page new users should see when they are not registered to use the app. However this presents 2 issues for me which is when the person logins in and hits the back button it goes back to the login page and I don't want that to happen. Also when the user credentials is stored and they open the app it still goes to the login page for a moment and then goes into the app.

How can I stop this from happening? Do I have to implement a cookie/session type login system?

My code is below

HTML

```
<div id="home">

    <div id="launcherPage" data-role="page">
        <!-- I'm just here waiting for deviceReady -->
    </div>


    <div id="loginPage" data-role="page">

        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>CHUNE</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">    

            <form id="loginForm">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" placeholder="Username" />
            </div>

            <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password" />
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Login" id="submitButton">
            </form>
            <div style="text-align: center;">Or</div> <!--need to center-->
            <a href="./register.html" data-role="button">Register</a>

        </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>&copy; KewsPlus</h4>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
 function init() {
document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceReady, true);
delete init;
```

}

```
 function checkPreAuth() {
console.log("checkPreAuth");
var form = $("#loginForm");
if(window.localStorage["username"] != undefined && window.localStorage["password"] != undefined) {
    $("#username", form).val(window.localStorage["username"]);
    $("#password", form).val(window.localStorage["password"]);
    handleLogin();
}
}

function handleLogin() {
var url = 'http://kewsplus.com/includes/login.php';
var form = $("#loginForm");    
//disable the button so we can't resubmit while we wait
$("#submitButton",form).attr("disabled","disabled");
var u = $("#username", form).val();
var p = $("#password", form).val();
if(u != '' && p!= '') {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: {username:u,password:p},
        dataType: "jsonp",
        crossDomain: "true",
        jsonp : "onJSONPLoad",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data = 1) {
                //store
                window.localStorage["username"] = u;
                window.localStorage["password"] = p;             
                $.mobile.changePage("featuredtracks.html");
            }  else {
                navigator.notification.alert("Your login failed", function() {});
            }
        }
    }); //$.ajax
       $("#submitButton").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
 else {
    navigator.notification.alert("You must enter a username and password", function() {});
    $("#submitButton").removeAttr("disabled");
}
return false;
}

function deviceReady() {
console.log("deviceReady");
$("#loginPage").on("pageinit",function() {
    console.log("pageinit run");
    $("#loginForm").on("submit",handleLogin);
    checkPreAuth();
});
$.mobile.changePage("#loginPage");
    });
```

Comment: why not just override the backbutton behaviour? http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#backbutton

Answer (score 1):

1. To prevent the back function, as soon as you load your new page (featuredtracks.html) you'll want override the back button by attaching to the PhoneGap provided event 'backbutton'. From [PhoneGap API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton):

   ```
   document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

   function onBackKeyDown() {
       // Handle the back button
   }
   ```
2. For preventing the login page from showing for a second when the credentials are saved, consider making your first page like a splash screen. The page will decide whether to load the login page or the main page (featuredtrack.html I assume). So instead of always loading your login page first, load a different page that will show some image or something well it decides whether to load login.html or featuredtracks.html.

   Note that now you'll want to override the backbutton for the login page as well, so that the user can't hit back and go to the loading/splash screen page.

Comment: The only time I have an issue with the back button it is with the login page. Otherwise I don't want to remove back button functionality for the user. Is there a way to do that in terms of saying you can go back just not to the login screen.

Comment: call document.removeEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false); in the onBackKeyDown Function, this sets the backbutton behavior back to default.

Comment: If you app is a multi-page app (and not a SPA), then in the onBackKeyDown function you could check window.referrer to see if you came from the login page. Otherwise you could maintain some history info if your app is a single page app.

Comment: It is multi page so the window.referrer seems to be a better solution.

Comment: what about using a jquery mobile dialog page for the login form? Since it doesn't save in memory the app should exit if it tries to go back to that point?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with jquery mobile to know, but it's your app so give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

```
            function deviceReady() {
            document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e){
            if($.mobile.activePage.is("#yourPageName")){
            navigator.notification.confirm('Do you want to exit the application?',confirmCallback, 'YourTitle');
               } 
            }, false);
```

}

```
          function confirmCallback(buttonIndex) {
           if(buttonIndex == 1) {
           navigator.app.exitApp();
            return true;
                 }
              else {
                return false;
                    }
         }
```

Try the above code.it's worked for me.